# Android - Running my app has an error within super.onCreate

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a simple paint app using the Android Paint module.

When running my app, it gives me an error in "Run", saying that there's a problem at line 14, which is the line which by default is created in my mainActivity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

None of it is underlined in my code, I can't find any errors at all in my code (including in my activity_main.xml!).

MainActivity.java: https://pastebin.com/zhEbBYdQ

activity_main.xml:https://pastebin.com/jPsA0gMX

CanvasView.java: https://pastebin.com/GctVDz5B

Any ideas? I've tried clean + rebuild, I've tried com.example.R etc.

Full error log: https://pastebin.com/26TebLhy

Thanks in advance. (New to StackOverflow - I have problems putting in code directly to these posts so I hope PasteBin is okay).

Comment: Could you provide activity_main layout

Comment: and also full `CanvasView` class

Comment: please add all the relevant code: your mainActivity.java and activity_main.xml

Comment: You should add all of the relevant code here directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CanvasView is in the package `evansspeak.paint1`, in main_activity however you are trying to inflate it from `*com*.evanspeak.Paint1`. Fix either one to be the same.

Check that the case matches as well (preferably all lower case)